# ReduceByKey and parititionBy in Spark

Tags: apache-spark

In Learning Spark book they write:

> For operations that act on a single RDD, such as reduceByKey(),
>   running on a **pre-partitioned** RDD will cause all the values for each
>   key to be computed **locally** on a single machine, requiring only the
>   final, locally reduced value to be sent from each worker node back to
>   the master.

However, in the [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33875623/reducebykey-function-in-spark) the author is saying, no pre-partitioning is needed because:

> For reduceByKey(), the first quality aggregates elements of the same
>   key with the provided associative reduce function **locally** first on
>   each executor and then eventually aggregated across executors.

So, why does a book suggestes pre-partitioning if reduceByKey() will anyway aggregares elements on each executor first without shuffeling the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The book doesn't really suggest pre-partitioning. It only describes the behavior of `*ByKey` methods when applied to partitioned `RDD`. Considering that partitioning itself *is a shuffle*, making a conclusion, that you should preemptively partitioned your data for a *single* `reduceByKey`, is unjustified.

In fact if data contains *N* values with *K* unique keys and `P` partitions, the size of the shuffle in the scenario `reduceByKey` ∘  `partitionBy` is always greater and equal than the size of the shuffle with `reduceByKey` alone.

If your going to apply *multiple* amortized cost of `partitionBy` followed by a set of `*byKey` or `*Join`applications might be lower than the cost of applying `*byKey` methods. Similarly if you've already shuffle the data as a part of different operation and you're going to apply shuffling operation later, yous should try to preserve existing partitioning. This however doesn't imply that you should always prefer to `partitionBy` first.

Comment: If I understood it correctly, there is no need to to partitionBy if I want to apply reduceByKey only once, correct?

Answer (score 1):

The answer above pretty much summed up thereduceByKey and partitionBy methods.

To Answer your question, you do not need to apply partitionBy before calling reduceByKey.